# can't access eager loaded laravel data result Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

```
$class = json_decode (Class::with(array('members'))->where('id', 1)->get());
```

I call `$class->name;`get trying to get property of non-object

`var_dump($class)` got

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#305 (12) 
    { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["name"]=> string(15) "chemistry" 
    ["days"]=> string(2) "30" 
    ["started_at"]=> string(10) "2015-02-15" 
    ["complete_at"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" 
    ["completed"]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2015-03-20 10:27:02" 
    ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2015-03-20 10:27:02" 
    ["deleted_at"]=> NULL 
    ["members"]=> array(8) 
    { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#289 (3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(6) "John" ["pivot"]=> object(stdClass)#306 (2) { ["class_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["member_id"]=> string(1) "1" } } 
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#326 (3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(5) "Elly" ["pivot"]=> object(stdClass)#322 (2) { ["class_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["member_id"]=> string(1) "2" } } 
    [2]=> object(stdClass)#325 (3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["name"]=> string(8) "Chris" ["pivot"]=> object(stdClass)#324 (2) { ["class_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["member_id"]=> string(1) "3" } } } } }
```

Below also get Trying to get property of non-object

```
foreach($class->members as $member){
   var_dump($member->name);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `json_decode` on an Eloquent result collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest, instead of using **->get()**, to use **->first()** since you're trying to fetch a single record.

```
$class = Class::with(array('members'))->where('id', 1)->first();
```

This will return a single object, not an array of objects.

If you want to fetch more than one model, you can use get and then foreach through the Classes and then inside the foreach for the classes, you can foreach through the members of a single class.

**Example: (single record)**

```
$class = Class::with(array('members'))->where('id', 1)->first();
foreach($class->members as $member)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($member);
}
```

**Example #2: (More than one result)**
If you want to get more than one class (assuming you dont have that where clause that limits the query to a single result).

```
$classes = Class::with(array('members'))->where('id', 1)->get();

foreach($classes as $class)
{
    //Data for a single Class model from this collection:
    foreach($class->members as $member) {
        //Data for a single member for a single class
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank @Ivanka. By the way, I can't search by   `$classes = Class::with(array('members'))->where(anme'', 'chemistry')->first();` ti cause  `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous `

Comment: Is that a typo? Shouldn't be $classes = Class::with(array('members'))->where(**'name'**,'=', 'chemistry')->first();
*note this will return the first result of the query.

Comment: Not typo error. Integrity constraint violation. Actually, it said SQL error. @Ivanka `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous (SQL: select `id`, `name`, `member_class`.`class_id` as `pivot_class_id`, `member_class`.`member_id` as `pivot_member_id` from `members` inner join `member_class` on `members`.`id` = `member_class`.`member_id` where `member_class`.`class_id` in (1))`

Comment: i can search by id as you example but I can't search by class name. sql error displayed. And my class name is unique()

Comment: As you are selecting data from two tables that both contain a field called id, hence why you receive the `Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous... `error.

If you try the same query again but define which id you wish to select using dot notation in the form `table`.`id` & it should work.

Comment: Yes @ivanka, problem is I want to get selected columns from members table ('id', 'name'). I can select columns with searching by id. if I don't select column, it's work. Should or Should not addSelect to query ?

Comment: Just select them with the table. For example if you want the name and the id of a member just type (I assume that your member's table is called `members`) `memebrs`.`id`, `members`.`name`.

Comment: I tried as u said, but still got error. Anyway thank @Ivanka. It will be next step.